# Why did Voldemort want Florean Fortescue captured and subsequently killed?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, character-motivation

Florean Fortescue was said to be captured and subsequently killed by Death Eaters during the Second Wizarding War (the capture happened in 1996, as mentioned in *Half-Blood Prince*).

> A few windows were boarded up, including those of Florean Fortescue’s Ice Cream Parlor.

**What was the reason for the Death Eaters capturing and later killing Florean Fortescue?**

Comment: Tom Riddle must have really hated ice cream as a child.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 Or **loved** it. Maybe he captured him so he could have his own private supply.

Comment: @TheDarkLord, Now we know why they're called *Death Eaters*.

Comment: Perhaps the Dark Lord and the Death Eaters just wanted some ice cream.

Comment: Ice cream headaches drives him to do **bad** things.

Comment: He was an aficionado of *paleo diet*.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

It's a left-over bit from a dropped plot point.  The following quote from Rowling I found at [the Harry Potter wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Florean_Fortescue), originally from [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/florean-fortescue):

> Florean is a descendant of Dexter, and I originally planned Florean to be the conduit for clues that I needed to give Harry during his quest for the Hallows, which is why I established an acquaintance fairly early on. At this stage, I imagined the **historically-minded Florean might have a smattering of information on matters as diverse as the Elder Wand and the diadem of Ravenclaw, the information having been passed down in the Fortescue family from their august ancestor**. As I worked my way nearer to the point where such information would become necessary, I caused Florean to be kidnapped, intending him to be found or rescued by Harry and his friends.
>
> The problem was that when I came to write the key parts of Deathly Hallows I decided that Phineas Nigellus Black was a much more satisfactory means of conveying clues. Florean's information on the diadem also felt redundant, as I could give the reader everything he or she needed by interviewing the Grey Lady. All in all, I seemed to have had him kidnapped and killed for no reason. **He is not the first wizard whom Voldemort murdered because he knew too much (or too little)**, but he is the only one I feel guilty about because it was all my fault

Comment: Most of this quote is irrelevant, and could definitely be shortened.

Comment: you dont really answer the question about the death eaters or voldemort, just pasted a block quote that meanders into rowling just killed him for no reason.

Comment: @Edlothiad I don't see that at all.  It explains what he was intended for that would have gotten him taken and killed (a conduit of information that Harry needed) and why he was not used that way, leading to the fact that he was taken and killed, but we never (in the book) discovered why.

Comment: I disagree - I think it answers the question perfectly. What is wrong with pasting a block of text? It's literally the author's answer to the asked question...

Comment: @Edlothiad This answers the question perfectly. It explains the issue and why it exists.

Comment: @SethWhite it literally does nothing to address if the issue was covered in the book. its just like, heres this quote, read this, maybe it answers what your looking for somewhere in this wall of text.

Comment: @Himarm The question doesn't ask whether the issue was covered in the book.

Comment: @Himarm It pretty clearly indicates that the issue is *not* covered in the book: "a *dropped* plot point", "[Rowling] had him kidnapped and killed *for no reason*"....

Comment: Sounds like the "word of God" answer is that she knew too much.

Comment: **tl;dr** Florean was a history buff that had intel on the Hallows and the founders' artifacts. Kidnapped to put him in place to give said intel probably after the Malfoy manor escape sequence but that plot point got dropped in favor of interrogating the Grey Lady.

Answer (score 3):

### We don't know Voldemort's/Death Eaters' motivation.

> ‘Did you hear about Florean Fortescue, Remus?’ asked Bill
> ‘Dragged off, by the look of his place.’
>
> ‘Why?’ asked Ron, while Mrs Weasley pointedly glared at Bill.
>
> ‘Who knows? He must’ve upset them somehow. He was a
> good man, Florean.’
>  <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*</sub>

### From Pottermore - Rowling decided to kill him off for no reason.

> All in all, I seemed to have had him kidnapped and killed for no reason. He is not the first wizard whom Voldemort murdered because he knew too much (or too little), but he is the only one I feel guilty about, because it was all my fault.
>  <sub>By J. K. Rowling on [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/florean-fortescue)</sub>

Comment: In your quest to avoid your "wall of text" as you put it, stating that "Rowling decided to kill him off for no reason" seriously undersells her actual reasoning. She *had* a reason originally. That reason eventually evolved. That context is important in understanding *why* Fortescue died "for no reason." As it is, your answer sounds like Rowling just decided the character needed to randomly die, when that wasn't the case at all. It eventually was the result, but that wasn't the intent. And the question is asking why that is.

Comment: @Ellesedil the question isnt asking about why Rowling decided to not go forward with the Florean, its asking for the Death eaters motives. The answer is, we dont know the motives. as an aside, we know out of world that she simply wanted a random "named" person to die to the death eaters, and Florean fit the bill. the rest of the quote is superfluous as it has no effect on answering the question, as asked.

Comment: Then why include Rowling's quote at all?

Comment: @Ellesedil i included it as an aside, to show that while the books show no motive, Rowling herself had commented on the issue on Pottermore, and sheds an out of world reason for the death, and again all you need for that  to satisfy the question is that she simply killed him off, and that behind the scenes the death eaters and voldemort still have, no motive, as written.

Comment: I think this is simply a matter of interpreting the question.  It actually asks: "What was the reason for the Death Eaters capturing and later killing Florean Fortescue?", which we are interpreting as "Why would JK Rowling have them do that?" and her motivations are important in that response.  You're reading it as "What were they thinking when they did that?"  Not sure which the OP meant, but he's got an acceptable answer to either one now.

Comment: Since when is giving too much of an answer a bad thing? Your answer is just as long as the other one, yet cuts out vital information that many (most?) readers would appreciate.

Comment: Your first quote is pretty useless - all it says is that a few characters in one scene don't know why FF was kidnapped, not that we the readers never find out. Your second quote doesn't make much sense without the surrounding context as supplied in the other answer (and any JKR quote is dubious anyway).

Comment: @KonradRudolph actually, no. The context is not relevant, because she never included it in her book, since it wasn't included in the book, she did just kill him for no reason, in world, and out of world. Rowlings decision to have him killed and even why SHE wanted him killed isnt the question were dealing with here, the question were dealing with is why did the DEATH EATERS want him killed, and in world and Rowling agrees, that he died for no apparent reason.

Comment: Why does this answer have so many down votes, when it provides better information that the other one??? Man HNQ is wonky....

Comment: @Randal'Thor Since most HP users are ... skeptical... of Rowlings after the fact statements in relation to the books, i included the only relevant in work information available, IN world we dont know why the death eaters took him, proven by my quote. Out of world rowling had some crazy fantasy about side plots , but none of that maters, because in the end she simply had him killed off, and she agree's to us the reader, it was for no apparent reason.

Comment: @Himarm Never mind, I agree. I thought the context implied that Voldemort abducted Fortescue because, well, he knew too much. But on rereading the full quote, this is in fact nowhere implied. Rather, the abduction was always going to be pure happenstance, even when he was intended to be rescued by Harry.

Comment: @methuseus nothing that i cut out was vital for the question asked, the question is not asking about cut plot points, its simply asking about the motivation of the death eaters for kidnapping and killing Florean. He was simply a random target, as Rowling herself confirms, the cut plot points are that, potentially Harry would save him, it didnt include any more reason for the abduction beyond random happenstance.